# MongoDB print only one value of a collection. JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js, mongoose-schema

I'm having a problem with MongoDB console.logging only one data of a collection. I've already searched like infinite topics about this, but none of them does exactly what I want.
I want to get one *number* data from my mongoose database. (I'm creating a discord.js bot)
This is what the database looks like:

```js
_id: 61bb8dc5a23c9a077066abf0
user: "soki#2400"
userId: "466270219132731392"
amount: 16
__v: 0
```

and I want to `console.log()` the value of `amount`.

This is my code now:

```js
console.log(giftsSchema.find({"_id": 0},{"user": msg.author.tag},{"userId": msg.author.id}).amount);
```

So what I want it to print is:

```js
16
```

But it prints

```js
undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean to search on two fields `user` and `userId`. You should use this:

```
giftsSchema.findOne(
    {"user": msg.author.tag, "userId": msg.author.id}, // query
    function (err, user) { 
       console.log(user.amount); 
    });
```

If you want to use projection so that only the amount field is returned, then supply a second param with the fields you want 1 and don't want 0.

```
giftsSchema.findOne(
    {"user": msg.author.tag, "userId": msg.author.id}, // query
    {_id: 0, amount: 1}, // projection
    function (err, user) { 
        console.log(user.amount);
    });
```

In your example you are providing 3 parameters `{"_id": 0}`, `{"user": msg.author.tag}`, and `{"userId": msg.author.id}`. With [find()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find) the first param is the query/filter. So in your code you are querying for all records where `_id` = 0 and I don't think you want that. The second param is for projection, and you provided an invalid object for that, projection values should only be 1 or 0 like your first param. Third param is for options, and doesn't come into play here.

You want to query on multiple fields by having them in single object like this `{ field1 : value1, field2 : value2 }`. I also think you only want one result, so you should use [findOne()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne) instead so you only get a single object in return and not an array of objects.

Also, Mongoose is asynchronous. So you should make an `async` function and `await` for the result. Or you can provide a callback function as shown in my example. NOTE: I don't handle the `err` case in my example.

Answer (score 0):

`.find()` method will return a Promise. You should first **wait** for that Promise to resolve before logging the result. Try doing it this way:

```js
const someFunction = async () => {
  let result = await giftsSchema.find({
    "user": msg.author.tag, "userId": msg.author.id
  }, {
    _id: 0, amount: 1
  });
  
  console.log('Result: ', result.amount);
}
```